# How to create a custom random distribution function?

Tags: c++, c++11, math, random

Normally I generate values using [the built in random functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), but now I need to create a random distribution of the form

```
f(x) = k*log(x) + m
```

**Is it possible to define a custom random distribution function?** For my actual model I have `x = [1, 1.4e7), k = -0.905787102751, m = 14.913170454`. Ideally I would like it to work how the current built-in distributions do:

```
int main() 
{
    std::mt19937 generator;

    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist(0.0, 1.0);
    my_distribution my_dist(0.0, 10.0); // Distribution using f(x)

    double uni_val = dist(generator);
    double log_val = my_dist(generator);
}
```

Comment: There's as much math as C++ is this question. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling, for instance.

Comment: What is the domain ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust For the initial problem it was between 1 -> 1.4e7. I added an answer for how I solved it.

Comment: Please specify the expected range for the parameters `m` and `k` as well as the range. In particular, is `x` ever considered `<1`?

Comment: @Walter I've added my actual model values as an edit in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I followed @jwimberley's idea pretty much to the point, and thought I would share my results here. I created a class that does the following:

1. Constructor arguments:

   - [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) (normalised or un-normalised), which is the
     *integral* of the [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function).
   - Lower and upper bound of the distribution
   - (optional) Resolution that indicates how many sample points of the CDF we should take.
2. Calculate a mapping from CDF -> random number *x*. This is our inverse CDF function.
3. Generate a random point by:

   - Generate a random probability *p* between `(0, 1]` using `std::random`.
   - Binary search in our mapping for CDF value that corresponds to *p*. Return the *x* that was calculated together with the CDF. Optional linear integration between nearby "buckets" is provided, otherwise we will get *n* == resolution discrete steps.

The code:

```
// sampled_distribution.hh
#ifndef SAMPLED_DISTRIBUTION
#define SAMPLED_DISTRIBUTION

#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T = double, bool Interpolate = true>
class Sampled_distribution
{
public:
    using CDFFunc = T (*)(T);

    Sampled_distribution(CDFFunc cdfFunc, T low, T high, unsigned resolution = 200) 
        : mLow(low), mHigh(high), mRes(resolution), mDist(0.0, 1.0)
    {
        if (mLow >= mHigh) throw InvalidBounds();

        mSampledCDF.resize(mRes + 1);
        const T cdfLow = cdfFunc(low);
        const T cdfHigh = cdfFunc(high);
        T last_p = 0;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < mSampledCDF.size(); ++i) {
            const T x = i/mRes*(mHigh - mLow) + mLow;
            const T p = (cdfFunc(x) - cdfLow)/(cdfHigh - cdfLow); // normalising 
            if (! (p >= last_p)) throw CDFNotMonotonic();
            mSampledCDF[i] = Sample{p, x};
            last_p = p;
        }
    }

    template <typename Generator>
    T operator()(Generator& g) 
    {
        T cdf = mDist(g);
        auto s = std::upper_bound(mSampledCDF.begin(), mSampledCDF.end(), cdf);
        auto bs = s - 1;
        if (Interpolate && bs >= mSampledCDF.begin()) { 
            const T r = (cdf - bs->prob)/(s->prob - bs->prob);
            return r*bs->value + (1 - r)*s->value;
        }
        return s->value;
    }

private:
    struct InvalidBounds : public std::runtime_error { InvalidBounds() : std::runtime_error("") {} };
    struct CDFNotMonotonic : public std::runtime_error { CDFNotMonotonic() : std::runtime_error("") {} };

    const T mLow, mHigh;
    const double mRes;

    struct Sample { 
        T prob, value; 
        friend bool operator<(T p, const Sample& s) { return p < s.prob; }
    };

    std::vector<Sample> mSampledCDF;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> mDist;
};

#endif
```

Here are some plots of the results. For a given PDF, we need to analytically calculate the CDF by integration first.

**Log-linear**
[image: Log-linear distribution]

**Sinusoidal**
[image: Sinusoidal distribution]

You can try this out yourself with the following demo:

```
// main.cc
#include "sampled_distribution.hh"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    auto logFunc = [](double x) { 
        const double k = -1.0;
        const double m = 10;
        return x*(k*std::log(x) + m - k); // PDF(x) = k*log(x) + m
    };
    auto sinFunc = [](double x) { return x + std::cos(x); }; // PDF(x) = 1 - sin(x)

    std::mt19937 gen;
    //Sampled_distribution<> dist(logFunc, 1.0, 1e4);
    Sampled_distribution<> dist(sinFunc, 0.0, 6.28);
    std::ofstream file("d.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) file << dist(gen) << std::endl;
}
```

The data is plotted with python.

```
// dist_plot.py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = np.loadtxt("d.txt")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bins = np.arange(d.min(), d.max(), (d.max() - d.min())/50)
ax.hist(d, edgecolor='white', bins=bins)
plt.show()
```

Run the demo with:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ main.cc -o main; ./main; python dist_plot.py
```

Comment: There a several things that one could say about this code, but this really belongs to code review.

Comment: @Walter The post doesn't ask for a review. This is the answer of how I created _a custom random distribution_, answering my own question. I'm honestly surprised over the downvote.

Comment: Your code is far from optimal. First, you should at least test for monotonicity of the CDF. Second, you could implement a better way to invert it, for example using a spline or polynomial interpolation. Third, if you request from the user both PDF and CDF, you could invert the latter using Newton-Raphson, which can be converged to machine precision. Finally, this is overkill for your initial problem.

Comment: @Walter I appreciate the feedback. All of your comments have merit -- my experience on the subject is limited and I tried my best at implementing that serves my needs. Regarding it being overkill: I tried to follow the idea from jwimberley, what could I have done instead?

Comment: @Walter There should be no need to test for monotonicity, a *valid* CDF is always monotonically non-decreasing since any valid PDF must be non-negative.  You'd have to modify a binary search for discrete distributions though.

Comment: I've implemented something like this before. I did a few things differently. First, my class accepts a lambda function for the PDF and numerically computes the CDF, or accepts an optional lambda-function CDF. This is more realistic for many clients of the code who might not have an analytic CDF. Second, I agree that the binary search is not the most efficient inversion method. I used a Newton-Raphson like algorithm. Numerical integration and Newton-Raphson are implemented in the GSL library to avoid doing that manually.

Comment: A Newton-Raphson root finder also has much better convergence than binary search.

Comment: @Walter I appreciate the effort made by pingul to show a complete solution to the question. If you don't like the code style, you are free to suggest precisely what to improve or, even better, to edit the answer yourself.

Comment: @HAL9000 I'm very surprised about your comment. I refrain from editing other people's posts (apart from simple typo/grammar issues), but have provided my own complete answer (with a link to the code posted on code review) already 18 months ago.

Answer (score 6):

This is very possible, but its as much of a math problem as a C++ problem. The most general method for creating a pseudo-random number generator is [Inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). Essentially, the CDF of any PDF is uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 (if this isn't apparent, just remember that the value of the CDF is a probability and think on this). So, you simply need to sample a random uniform number between 0 and 1 and apply the inverse of the CDF.

In your case, with $f(x) = k*log(x) + m$ (you haven't specified bounds, but I assume they are between 1 and some positive number > 1) the CDF and its inverse are quite messy - a problem I leave up to you! The implementation in C++ will look like

```
double inverseCDF(double p, double k, double m, double lowerBound, double upperBound) {
     // do math, which might include numerically finds roots of equations
}
```

Then the generation code will look something like

```
class my_distribution {
     // ... constructor, private variables, etc.
     template< class Generator >
     double operator()( Generator& g ) {
          std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist(0.0, 1.0);
          double cdf = dist(g);
          return inverseCDF(cdf,this->k,this->m,this->lowerBound,this->upperBound);
     }
}
```

Comment: This was great advise, and led me on the right path. Upvoted. I added an answer that outlines how I implemented it -- was this what you had in mind? Please suggest improvements if you feel anything is at fault.

Answer (score 2):

I like a lot the concepts presented here, leading to a very slim, yet very powerful generator. I just did some cleaning embedding c++17 features, I was going to edit pingul's answer, but it came out quite different, so I am posting it separated.

```
#pragma once

#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T = double, bool Interpolate = true>
class SampledDistribution {
  struct Sample { 
    T prob, value; 
    Sample(const T p, const T v): prob(p), value(v) {}
    friend bool operator<(T p, const Sample& s) { return p < s.prob; }
  };

  std::vector<Sample> SampledCDF;

public:
  struct InvalidBounds:   std::runtime_error { using std::runtime_error::runtime_error; };
  struct CDFNotMonotonic: std::runtime_error { using std::runtime_error::runtime_error; };

  template <typename F>
  SampledDistribution(F&& cdfFunc, const T low, const T high, const unsigned resolution = 256) {
    if (low >= high) throw InvalidBounds("");
    SampledCDF.reserve( resolution );
    const T cdfLow = cdfFunc(low);
    const T cdfHigh = cdfFunc(high);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < resolution; ++i) {
      const T x = (high - low)*i/(resolution-1) + low;
      const T p = (cdfFunc(x) - cdfLow)/(cdfHigh - cdfLow); // normalising 
      if (p < SampledCDF.back()) throw CDFNotMonotonic("");
      SampledCDF.emplace_back(p, x);
    }
  }

  template <typename Engine>
  T operator()(Engine& g) {
    const T cdf = std::uniform_real_distribution<T>{0.,1.}(g);
    auto s = std::upper_bound(SampledCDF.begin(), SampledCDF.end(), cdf);
    if (Interpolate && s != SampledCDF.begin()) { 
      auto bs = s - 1;
      const T r = (cdf - bs->prob)/(s->prob - bs->prob);
      return r*bs->value + (1 - r)*s->value;
    }
    return s->value;
  }
};
```

And here is a test main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SampledDistribution.hpp"

int main() {
  std::mt19937 gen;
  auto sinFunc = [](double x) { return x + std::cos(x); }; // PDF(x) = 1 - sin(x)

  unsigned resolution = 32;
  std::vector<int> v(resolution,0);
  SampledDistribution dist(sinFunc, 0.0, 6.28, resolution);

  for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) 
    ++v[ static_cast<size_t>(dist(gen)/(6.28) * resolution) ];

  for (auto i: v)
    std::cout << i << '\t' << std::string(i/100, '*') << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp && ./a.out
2882    ****************************
2217    **********************
1725    *****************
1134    ***********
690     ******
410     ****
182     *
37  
34  
162     *
411     ****
753     *******
1163    ***********
1649    ****************
2157    *********************
2796    ***************************
3426    **********************************
4048    ****************************************
4643    **********************************************
5193    ***************************************************
5390    *****************************************************
5796    *********************************************************
5979    ***********************************************************
6268    **************************************************************
6251    **************************************************************
6086    ************************************************************
5783    *********************************************************
5580    *******************************************************
5111    ***************************************************
4646    **********************************************
3964    ***************************************
3434    **********************************
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out elsewhere, the standard method for sampling any PDF is to invert its CDF at a point chosen uniformly random from the interval [0,1].

In case of your particular problem, the CDF is a simple function, but its inverse is not. In this case, one may invert it using traditional numerical tools, such as Newton-Raphson iteration. Unfortunately, you failed to specify the range for `x` or the allowed choices for the parameters `m` and `k`. I have implemented this for general `m`, `k`, and range ([and posted it on code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/161953/implementation-of-logarithmic-random-distribution-satisfying-randomnumberdistrib)) to satisfy the C++ [RandomNumberDistribution concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomNumberDistribution).